# how does a charge pump boost works?

Tags: power-supply, analog, charge-pump

I have looked how charge pump works and I can understand for example the doubler voltage as it based on charge/discharge of the capacitor. as I have asked one of my student colleagues how it works, his answer is: the charge pump adds the supply voltage per stage that I don't understand. another question is related to the stages as well, how can I know how many switches/diodes are required per stage?
best regards,

Comment: Provide a link to the specific part or at least a link to something that you have read that confuses you. Explain specifically what part you don't understand. I mean, do we start explaining ohms law or does someone answering assume you know about capacitor formulas and MOSFETs etc. Provide a link!

Comment: There are many circuits which can be called a charge pump. You are probably referring to the type which is used to create a higher supply voltage. You could start reading on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump  and then come back here when you still have a question.

Comment: I have looked at Wikipedia link, I understand it but it looks like we need an inverter for each stage and an inverter is a complex circuit. I thought that with a couple of the capacitor and one transistor as a switch we can make one stage of charge pump. the link http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/charge-pump-option-ldo-and-inductor-based-regulators

Comment: *an inverter is a complex circuit* Geez, sorry but in my opinion an inverter it is about as simple as you can get circuits wise on a chip and in a CMOS process. An inverter (PMOS + NMOS) is **not** a complex circuit. I'd understand if you think that a JK flip-flop is a complex circuit but not an inverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start out like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2freKlB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then go like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGczw.png)</sup>

I made C1 ridiculously large for the sake of the example.  In real life you might want to have two switched caps and alternate them.  A similar technique can give you a negative voltage.

Comment: Nice schematics. It would be better to show where the output of the charge pump is meant to be, i.e. where the load is placed. This would help understanding the circuit by those who don't know it.

Comment: I understand the schematic now. nevertheless, my question how can in an integrated circuit is implemented as i heard that it is a couple of capacitor as an external component and one switch for one stage which gives an output voltage Vout=Vin*(N+1) where N is the number of a stage. so, for example, i can know in advance how many components I ll need in my design.thanks

Comment: Unclear why you need to ask that. When I design a circuit (charge pump or otherwise) for use in a chip, I **don't care** how many components I need. On a chip the **size** is important as large size means large cost. You first determine how you can make the function you want so that it meets the requirements. That determines how many stages (N) you need. Then the required current determines how large the MOSFETs and capacitors need to be. It's not all formulas, it is **design** meaning it's like a puzzle and it has dependencies.

Comment: actually, I asked that because I am limited in size and I want ed to know how is the design flow is related to the size by knowing the most common integrated charge pump used. here, I can find many techniques doing the job of charge pump like the one in the link I have showed and the one the cristobol showed.thanks